# Heap size not getting increasing

Tags: apex

This is an academic exercise for self study purpose to understand how things work behind scenes.

Below is the code snippet

```
account a;
System.debug('Current Heap:::' + Limits.getHeapSize());
a = new account(name ='Account1');
System.debug('Current Heap:::' + Limits.getHeapSize());
system.debug(a);
a = new account(name = 'Account2');
System.debug('Current Heap:::' + Limits.getHeapSize());
system.debug(a);
```

step2->heap size is 1070
and i point a to the object whose name is Account1,heap size increases to 1090
in following step i repoint a to another object whose name is Account2,and
i expect to see an increase in Heap size.But it doesnt it remains 1090
Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

welcome to the forum.

When you point the variable a at the second instance of the Account, the first instance is lost to memory so the heap usage remains the same. Try it using a second variable or a list :)

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
for (integer x=0; x< 10; x++) {
    System.debug('Current Heap:::' + Limits.getHeapSize());
    accounts.add(new account(name ='Account ' + x));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by lost to memory?i thought it is there for garbage collection.But doesn't erase from memory?

Comment: Heap is the amount of memory being referenced by your running code. When you assign a to the second account, it is no longer referenced in your context and so it doesn't count to your memory usage. If you instead used b = account(name = 'Account2'); then you would see heap size increase because you are keeping reference to both.

Comment: oh okeis. now i understand.so can we say 'garbage'[unreferenced ] values never add to your heap size? because i thought ,it does.

Comment: yes, and thinks such as garbage collection etc. are provided by the platform and not something you have to worry about or control.